# Call to undefined function get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); in wp (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to access my css file in my directory but it shows fatal error message "Call to undefined function get_stylesheet_directory_uri();". Please help me to fix it.. Thanx

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/vendors/material-design-icons/material-icons.css">
```

Comment: The code isn't valid HTML, and you didn't provide the error message. How is anyone supposed to help?

Comment: Call to undefined function get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

Comment: It's pretty clear, the function doesn't exist. Which means that this file isn't including what it needs to, or the file that's including this file isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` **does** exist in WordPress. The reason why  you might be getting an undefined method error:

1. PHP is not enabled on your server
2. Make sure your file is a `.php` file and not `.html`
3. If it is a PHP file, then this file is not loading WordPress core. You can achieve this by including `wp_load.php` at the top of your php script.

   $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
    require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

If that does not help, post a link of your application or the file hiercharchy of your theme.

Comment: or a typo in the function's name, but in the question it is pronounced well :)